# How old is Tony Stark in the first Iron Man movie?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

A lot of people I know have no idea, even though they are hard core Iron Man fans.

I am not asking about the comics or the consistency of his age — I am asking what his age is mean to be in the first movie.

Comment: As established in the accepted answer on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/is-the-age-of-tony-stark-consistent-with-the-appearance-of-his-father-in-the-cap?lq=1, in *Iron Man* he’s somewhere between 39 and 46.